# openshift distribute pods in one project to specific nodes

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have 3 cpu nodes and 1 gpu node on my cluster. As a default, the
projects should deploy to the cpu nodes and only when specified to the
gpu nodes. I added `defaultNodeSelector: "graphic=cpu"` to the
projectConfig section in `master-config.yaml` to achieve this purpose.

The problem now when i create a deploymentConfig and assign it to the gpu
node using node selector, I get the error `pod node label selector conflicts with its project node label selector`.

I tried removing the defaultNodeSelector line and added
`nodeSelectorLabelBlacklist: - graphic=gpu` to the PodNodeConstraints
section in `master-config.yaml`, but this did not work at all. Despite this
config the pods of the default projects got scheduled to the gpu node :/

[master-config.yaml](https://pastebin.com/v88Lc73x)

Does any body has an Idea how to achieve such stuff?

Comment: in this particular project, do you want all workloads to land on this gpu node or just this specific deployment?

Comment: just one deployment on the gpu and the others on the cpu nodes

Comment: Could you post the formatted yaml of your master-config.yml for the 'admissionConfig.pluginConfig.PodNodeConstraints' part, as well as your deployment config. I don't know for sure yet but it looks like a typo. I know the clusterDefaultNodeSelector field but not defaultNodeSelector.

Comment: The defaultNodeSelector is mentioned here https://blog.openshift.com/deploying-applications-to-specific-nodes/ as well as in the documentation. I added the master config. The deploymentconfig is a normal one with nodeselector inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set here a cluster-wide configuration which cannot be overridden at the Pod level.

Probably, the simplest fix in this instance, assuming you have other projects that want to leverage the cluster-wide config is to edit the namespace for this particular project and set the `openshift.io/node-selector: ""`.

For each workload in this project then set the desired node as appropriate in each deployment or deploymentconfig. That should fix the issue for you.

Perhaps, if this is not a one off case for you, take a look at other scheduling features such as [taints and tolerations](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/scheduling/taints_tolerations.html) or [pod affinity](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/scheduling/pod_affinity.html)

Comment: This approach will be effortful, if we have many projects :/ I took a look on taints and tolerations. Ii did work for deploymentconfigs, but it is not possible to assign tolearions for buildconfigs :/

Comment: Yes as I said, it will be effortful if you have many projects that require a mix of using the gpu node and cpu node. In this particular case, since it seems the workloads using gpu might be sparse right? then perhaps using affinity towards those nodes in the desired deployments is the best option